# how i can create a shared partial view inside my asp.net mvc web application that can accept different types of objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, object-oriented-analysis

I am working on an asp.net MVC web application.and i have many model classes which represents servers, vm, PC, monitors, etc. And for each of these model classes there is a shared class which is used to populate third party API. so i have extended all my model classes using the shared class, as follow :-

```
 public class Server : CreateResource,  IValidatableObject
    {//code goes here}

 public class VM : CreateResource,  IValidatableObject
    {//code goes here}
 public class PC : CreateResource,  IValidatableObject
    {//code goes here}
```

and here is the CreateResource class:-

```
public class CreateResource
    {
        public CreateResource()
        {
            this.operation = new Operation5();
            this.createAccount = new CreateAccount();
        }
        public Operation5 operation { get; set; }
        public CreateAccount createAccount { get; set; }

    }
```

now the problem i am facing is that for all the model classes , i will be using the exact view for entering the CreateResource data when creating server,vm,pc objects. So at the server,vm,pc, etc main create/edit view i added references to the partial views as follow  (this is an example of the Server object):-

```
@model S.Models.Server

@Html.Partial("_PMCreateResource",Model.operation.Details)
    @Html.Partial("_PMCreateAccount",Model.createAccount.operation.Details.ACCOUNTLIST.ToList())
```

But the problem i am facing is that when the view is posted back to the Create/Edit action method  i have to define separate parameters to access the posted back models (one main model and 2 models representing the partial views) as follow (this is an example of the Server action method):-

```
[HttpPost]       
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(Server sj,Details4 d4,List<ACCOUNTLIST> al)
{
```

and to be able to only define the Server object as follow:-

```
[HttpPost]       
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(Server sj)
{
```

then i will need to pass the whole model to the partial view as follow (this is an example of the Server main view):-

```
@model S.Models.Server

@Html.Partial("_PMCreateResource",Model)
@Html.Partial("_PMCreateAccount",Model)
```

but passing the whole server, vm,pc, monitor models to the same partial view mean that i have to create separate partial views for each model class, since each partial view will be accepting different model object. so not sure if i can modify my code to achieve these 2 things:-

1. pass the whole model object to the partial view.so when posting back the view the post action method will only accept one model object as the parameter, instead of 3 parameters.
2. use a single shared view, which will accept different types of model objects?

not sure how i can achieve this?

Comment: Why don't you create a DisplayTemplate [link1](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETMVCDisplayTemplateAndEditorTemplatesForEntityFrameworkDbGeographySpatialTypes.aspx) [link2](http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2012/12/aspnet-mvc-display-and-editor-templates.html) for the Server, VM and PC?

Comment: Why should pass all of models to partial view and get only one of them will get?

Comment: @ali as i mentioned i have multiple model objects such as server, vm, monitor, pc, etc,,, while those are different model they all share the same CreateResource class... so inside the create/edit view for these model classes i need to pass the whole model object to the partial view to be able to only define one parameter inside the post edit and create action method,, as described inside my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `@HtmlPartial()`, use an `EditorTemplate` so that the `name` attributes of the controls are correctly prefixed.

Create an partial view named `CreateResource.cshtml` in the `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` folder (note that the name of the file must match the name of the class)

```
@model CreateResource
@Html.TextboxFor(m => m.operation.Details.SomeProperty)
....
for(int i = 0; i < Model.createAccount.operation.Details.ACCOUNTLIST.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.createAccount.operation.Details.ACCOUNTLIST[i].SomeProperty)
    ....
}
```

Then in the main view

```
@model S.Models.Server
Html.EditorFor(m => m) // generated the base controls
.... // controls specific to Server
```

Then to break the `EditorTemplate` into more manageable parts and allow you to reuse them, create additional templates for `Operation5` and `CreateAccount`

In `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Operation5.cshtml`

```
@model Operation5
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Details.SomeProperty)
....
```

and change the `CreateResource.cshtml` template to

```
@model CreateResource
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.operation)
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.createAccount)
```

and you can keep breaking this down to create an `EditorTemplate` for each nested model, including for the collection items, so assuming property `Details` is typeof `Detail` and property `ACCOUNTLIST` is typeof `List<AccountItem>`, then you would have

`/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/AccountItem.cshtml`

```
@model AccountItem
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SomeProperty)
```

`/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Detail.cshtml`

```
@model Detail
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SomeProperty)
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.ACCOUNTLIST) // generates the html for each item in the collection
```